# TailwindCSS in React: Content hard cut-off despite gradient

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a React app which includes a header that has a gradient from the background color at the top to transparent at the bottom. I have confirmed that this gradient works by setting the background to e.g. red and observed that it does become transparent at the bottom (thanks StackOverflow).

Now, my issue is that the page content below the header consists of a div that will gradually be filled with message elements and eventually overflow to disappear behind the header. Though, when the message elements disappear behind the header, they are cut off instead of disappearing with the gradient of the header. It looks like so, with the cut-off at the bottom of the header:

[image]

How can this be?

This is the context of the React app (App.js):

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col font-display bg-slate-50 h-screen">
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Chat />} />
          <Route path="/info" element={<Info />} />
        </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </main>
  );
}
```

This is my Header component:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="top-0 z-50 xl:px-64 lg:px-44 md:px-32 sm:px-14 xs:px-0 pt-2 bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-transparent">
      <div className="w-full flex xs:p-5 p-2 xs:flex-row flex-col xs:items-end items-center justify-between">
        <h1 className="sm:text-4xl text-2xl font-bold text-gray-600 border-b-2 border-green-400">
          REACT APP
        </h1>
        <nav className="md:mr-4 md:py-1 md:pl-4 flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center text-base xs:mt-0 mt-1">
          <NavLink to="/">
            <p>Chat</p>
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/info">
            <p>Info</p>
          </NavLink>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}
```

And finally, this is the Chat component (I removed the functionalities for better readability). It is the div with `id="messages-scroll"` that scrolls when the message elements overflow:

```
export default function Chat () {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
 

  return (
    <section className="flex flex-col h-full 2xl:mx-96 xl:mx-80 lg:mx-72 md:mx-40 sm:mx-20 mx-3 overflow-clip">
      <div
        ref={messagesEndRef}
        id="messages-scroll"
        className="flex w-full overflow-y-auto scroll-smooth px-5 mt-auto"
      >
        <div className="flex flex-1 flex-col mt-auto">
          {messages.map((message, index) => {
            if (message.role === "user") {
              return <UserMessage key={index} text={message.content} />;
            } else if (message.role === "assistant") {
              return <BotMessage key={index} text={message.content} />;
            }
            return null;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleInputSubmit}
        className="flex flex-row w-full h-14 mb-7 mt-2 px-5"
      >
        <input
          className="border-2 border-gray-400 rounded-md p-3 w-full h-full mr-1 shadow-xl focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none"
          type="text"
          value={inputValue}
          placeholder="Spørg dommeren..."
          onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="ml-1 py-2 px-4 rounded-md bg-green-400 hover:bg-green-300 shadow-xl hover:ease-in-out duration-150"
        >
          {renderContent()}
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can see in the demo I added above that the class works fine in this context. There must be something else going on that we can't see from here. Maybe post the rendered HTML in the demo.

Comment: FYI, a `main` element generally shouldn't contain the header or primary navigation of your site. It should contain content specific to the individual page. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main#usage_notes.

Comment: Thanks. From the demo I can see that black-to-white gradient works, which I already knew, but I can't see that e.g. a black-to-transparent works

Comment: Please update the demo to show the problem. That was my intent.

Comment: It works fine, `slate` is just almost white. Replacing it with `bg-red-500` shows that the gradient works

Comment: Not sure there's a `black-to-transparent`. But `bg-gradient-to-b from-black to-transparent` seems to work fine.

Comment: It seems it does work, and that my problem is an entirely different problem. I have a div that gets filled with messages over time and will overflow. When a message element disappears behind the header it cuts off at the edge of the header instead of disappearing with the gradient. I will try to rephrase my question. Thanks guys.

Comment: Question has been updated.